# Array inside a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

I've tried looking to see if this is possible, but I can't find my answer.

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
var defaults = {
 'background-color': '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 weekdays: {['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat']}
};
```

It just gives an error, and I've tried using `({...})` and `[{...}]` I'd like to be able to access the weekdays using something like:

```
defaults.weekdays[0];
```

is this possible?

Comment: You're not mentioning this, and no one has commented on it yet, but if you want a hyphen in a key like `background-color`, it needs to be quoted. Eg `"background-color": '#000'`

Comment: Quick note: `[]` is for arrays, `{}` is for objects

Comment: Thanks CresentFresh, I added the quotes, but it wasn't the problem I was running into :)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Kill the braces.

```
var defaults = {
 backgroundcolor: '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 weekdays: ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat']
};
```

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have a trailing comma after the end of the final ], or your code will break in IE7.

Comment: Really? I've only seen breakage in IE7, and I see it every time I refactor. Every single time. Perhaps IE6's behavior is nondeterministic. That's worse than failing every time, right?

Comment: I get "missing : after property id"

Comment: This works for me, as long as you put quotes around "background-color", as Crescent Fresh mentioned above.

Comment: Don't use the dash, or use quotes as mentioned.

Comment: If you have a comma after the last item in an Array or Object, it is invalid JavaScript syntax. JSLint will automate these checks for you: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Comment: This was actually fixed by integrating YUI Compressor into my build system. Trailing commas disappear.

Comment: How do you kill the braces, if it is coming from some third party website?

Comment: @Utpal-UrBestPal The third party site isn't returning json, then. You can read this as a string and remove the braces programmatically. I've had to do similar things when working with non-json that was almost json.

Answer (score 13):

```
// define
var foo = {
  bar: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
};

// access
foo.bar[2]; // will give you 'baz'
```

Comment: Can you do like var foo = { bar: [] } and then say foo.bar[7] = 'hi'; like you can when its outside of an object?

Answer (score 5):

```js
var data = {
  name: "Ankit",
  age: 24,
  workingDay: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
};

for (const key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    const element = data[key];
      console.log(key+": ", element);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are so organised you may declare the entire object from the outset (this comma-delimited list is called an object initializer):

```
const myObject = {
    string:     'Galactic Rainbows',
    color:      'HotPink',
    sociopaths: [ "Hitler", "Stalin", "Gates" ]
}
```

Alternatively, once you have declared the object,

```
  // this line is the declaration:
const myObject = {};  
  // it is equivalent to:
const myObject2 = new Object();
```

you may define its properties by giving them values:

```
myObject.string     = "Galactic Rainbows";
myObject.color      = "HotPink";
myObject.sociopaths = [ "Hitler", "Stalin", "Gates" ];
     //  ^properties  ^values
```

**All examples below assume the object is already declared** (as above)

I prefer to declare the array separately, like this, and then assign it to the object:

```
const weekdays    = [ 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat' ];
myObject.weekdays = weekdays;
myObject.weekdays[0] 
               // => 'sun'
```

But if you have already declared the object, it would be quicker to code:

```
myObject.weekdays = [ 'sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat' ];
```

But you **cannot** assign an array of arrays to the object like this:

```
myObject.girlsAndBoys[0] = [ "John", "Frank", "Tom"   ];   //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
myObject.girtsAndBoys[1] = [ "Jill", "Sarah", "Sally" ];   //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
```

To assign a two dimensional array to an object you have a few options. You can initialise the empty 2D array first:

```
myObject.girlsAndBoys    = [[]];
myObject.girlsAndBoys[0] = [ "John", "Frank", "Tom"   ]; 
myObject.girtsAndBoys[1] = [ "Jill", "Sarah", "Sally" ];
```

Or you may do it layer by layer:

```
const boys            = [ "John", "Frank", "Tom"   ];    
const girls           = [ "Jill", "Sarah", "Sally" ];
myObject.girlsAndBoys = [[ boys ],[ girls ]];
```

Alternatively you may do it all at once (after no more than the object declaration):

```
const myObject              = {};
myObject.girlsAndBoys       = [[ "John", "Frank", "Tom"   ],
                               [ "Jill", "Sarah", "Sally" ]];
myObject.girlsAndBoys[0][0] == "John";   // returns True
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var defaults = {

  "background-color": "#000",
  color: "#fff",
  weekdays: [
    {0: 'sun'},
    {1: 'mon'},
    {2: 'tue'},
    {3: 'wed'},
    {4: 'thu'},
    {5: 'fri'},
    {6: 'sat'}
  ]

};
               
console.log(defaults.weekdays[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
 webSiteName: 'StackOverFlow',
 find: 'anything',
 onDays: ['sun'     // Object "obj" contains array "onDays" 
            ,'mon',
            'tue',
            'wed',
            'thu',
            'fri',
            'sat',
             {name : "jack", age : 34},
              // array "onDays"contains array object "manyNames"
             {manyNames : ["Narayan", "Payal", "Suraj"]}, //                 
           ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to multiple arrays in an object. For instance, you want to record modules for different courses

```
var course = {
    InfoTech:["Information Systems","Internet Programming","Software Eng"],
    BusComm:["Commercial Law","Accounting","Financial Mng"],
    Tourism:["Travel Destination","Travel Services","Customer Mng"]
};
console.log(course.Tourism[1]);
console.log(course.BusComm);
console.log(course.InfoTech);
```