# How to model nested Array Data Structure of primitive Types

Tags: loopbackjs

I need to model a nested data structure with an array of an array of numbers. Ex:

```
"measures": [
  [1, 91.3],
  [2, 87.5],
  ...
```

I tried like this:

```
"mmeasures": {
  "type": [ [ "Number" ] ]
},
```

But it does not seem to work.

The corresponding [loopback docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/LoopBack+types#LoopBacktypes-Arraytypes) do not mention nested arrays.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain the business case you need this? It could be the case that a simply using and object with an array { [ ] } , could do the trick. Or maybe you need a matrix? [ ] [ ] . Other possibility to consider would be to use constructor i.e - let myArrOfArr = new Array(new Array( ));

Comment: I think the business case does not matter at all here, I asked a clear question. The matrix solution also does not work as it is not even valid JS.

Comment: Hi, so.. did you notice in my previous comment the part "It could be the case that a simply using and object with an array { [ ] } , could do the trick" that was exactly the solution you published as valid below :) . Asking about the business case I was just trying to understand to see if that would fit the case.

Comment: No it isn't the solution. I'm simply not using an object, neither in the model nor in the real data.

Comment: Hi, humm.. it looks like you're missing basic concepts of javascript, please check this sources and you'll possibly understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828924/array-inside-a-javascript-object

http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Answer (score 0):

An array of `any` typed values did the trick:

```
"mmeasures": {
  "type": [ "any" ]
},
```