# how do I make an array inside an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code:

```
var Memory ={
 
  personAbove: "someone",
  words: wordsMem = []  <<<<<this thing doesn't work
  
}
```

how do I make it work? how do I make "words" refrence an array of words inside the "Memory" object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array inside a JavaScript Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828924/array-inside-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Memory = {
  personAbove: "someone",
  words: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one , it might help you

```
var Memory ={
 
  personAbove: "someone",
  words: { wordsMem : []  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like this:

```
var Memory = {
      personAbove: "someone",
      words: [] //Now you can add any value is array
    }
```

You can parse this array value like this:  `Memory.words or Memory['words']` whichever you like.

You can read more about array and object here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make array inside an object

```
var Memory ={
 
  personAbove: "someone",
  words: { 
     wordsMem:["a","b","c"] 
  }
  
}
```

to access values inside array
`Memory["words"]["wordsMem][0]  //a`

or

`Memory.words.wordsMem[0] //a`

Answer (score 0):

Objects are constructed using key value pairs, so "personAbove" is a key for the value "someone". Similarly an array is a value, so all you need is a key.

```
let Memory = {
  personAbove: "someone",
  words: []
}
```

Sets the empty array as the value of Memory.wordsMem. Alternatively, you can define the wordsMem variable first, then reference it as the value of the words key.

```
let wordsMem = [];
let Memory = {
  personAbove: "someone",
  words: wordsMem
}
```

This sets wordsMem and Memory.words to point at the same array, so performing array operations on one will update the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaults = {
 backgroundcolor: '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 weekdays: ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat']
};
```

Source:
[Array inside a JavaScript Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828924/array-inside-a-javascript-object)